# How to malloc for getline implementation

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, getline

I'm trying to add `getline` support to [http-fs-wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/http-fs-wrapper/) and I have some malloc problems.

```
ssize_t _intercept_getdelim(int fd, char **lineptr, size_t *n, int delim)
{
    intercept_t *obj = intercept[fd];
    int counter;
    size_t nc = sizeof(char);

    counter = -1;
    while (obj->offset < obj->size)
    {
        ++counter;
        if (*lineptr) {
            *lineptr = realloc(*lineptr, (counter + 2) * nc);
        }
        else {
            *lineptr = malloc(nc);
        }
        _intercept_read(fd, lineptr[counter], nc);
        if (*lineptr[counter] == delim)
        {
           break;
        }
    }
    *n = counter ? counter + 1 : counter;
    *lineptr[counter + 2] = '\0';
    // Why do we need a *n when the return value is the same??
    return *n;
}
```

Here's the relevant section of `_intercept_read`:

```
size_t _intercept_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)
{
    memcpy(buf, obj->ra_buf+bo, count);
```

When I step through this in gdb, the second iteration throws a SIGSEGV (from memcpy -- it's not the ending `\0`, it's still inside the loop). I also don't quite get what's the difference between the `*n` of `getline`/`getdelim` and the return value.

Comment: Not an answer, but trying to wrap/replace every single io function sounds like a really bad way to implement virtual http fs. Only functions which *open* files should need to be hooked, and all they should need to do is open a pipe or local socket to a thread or process that does the http.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between n and the return value is that n is always the buffer size, but the return value can be -1 for error states per posix spec. You aren't fully handling EOF (it should return -1 if it hits EOF and hasn't read anything yet).

A note, reallocing for every character is fairly inefficient. The standard pattern is to double the buffer size each time it is necessary. This is another way the return value and n can differ, since n is the buffer size, which can be much larger than the read character count it returns.

You also don't need to special case a starting null pointer, realloc internally calls malloc in that case.

buf = realloc(buf...) is an unsafe pattern, realloc can return null, you have to save the realloc result to a temp variable and check it before assigning, otherwise you both leak memory and can reference a null pointer.

I don't think there's actually space for the trailing null you're adding to the buffer at the end there.

Comment: Well the problem is the sigsegv on the second iteration (from memcpy). Clearly I messed up by pointers. Care to tell me where?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
ssize_t _intercept_getdelim(int fd, char **lineptr, size_t *n, int delim)
{
    intercept_t *obj = intercept[fd];
    int counter = -1;
    char *c, *newbuf;

    *n = 1;
    *lineptr = malloc(*n);
    while (obj->offset < obj->size)
    {
        ++counter;
        if (counter >= *n)
        {
            if ((newbuf = realloc(*lineptr, *n  << 1)))
            {
                *n = *n << 1;
                *lineptr = newbuf;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }

        }
        c = *lineptr + counter;
        _intercept_read(fd, c, nc);
        if (*c == delim)
        {
           break;
        }
    }
    if (counter > -1)
    {
        *(*lineptr + ++counter) = '\0';
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do the initial malloc, since part of the goal of getdelim is permitting reusing the buffer (you've currently got a memory leak if someone tries to do this). But otherwise that is a cleaner usage of realloc. You may want to set errno to ENOMEM before returning -1 though depending on how much you care about posix spec compliance. Also, since you're not checking the buffer size before adding the trailing \0, that can still possibly overflow the buffer.